# Bootstrap navbar with left, centered, and right elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, navbar

I want a navbar on my website with three options in the center, the company name in the top-left, and an expanding dropdown menu in the top-right corner. However, after spending hours trying to implement different ones from the internet, none of them work for me. The formatting is always super off. Although, I found one where everything works correctly, except the  list that I have for the middle three elements displays them stacked instead of horizontal. I can assure that I have looked through all other questions on slack that are similar and none have solved my issue. Here it the code I have:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Left</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Explore</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Engage</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Experience</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Right</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And here is a screenshot of what it looks like with this component added in.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ3lP.jpg)

What is very interesting is that I had to import  at the top of my cover page component so that I could get my slideshow working. If I take out the slideshow, it sets up the navbar correctly.

So I either need to:

1) assign that stylesheet to only the cover component (it has been assigning it to the entire page)

OR

2) figure out how to center my current set up I have which is incredibly close to working.

Comment: as you're using bootstrap, why not just make your own column layout - after all that's the main point of bootstrap - responsive columns

Comment: @Pete can you elaborate? How would I set that up in a navbar?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ - you don't just have to stick with pre-defined columns of the navbar, you can create your own and give it the widths you want.  Also if you only want to apply styles to a single component, give it a unique class or id and target it, don't just stick to using bootstrap classes

Comment: @Pete I know I can use ids and unique classes, but as for this scenario, the stylesheet that I want is being applied to everything. If I could find what it is within the style sheet on the cover that is messing up my navbar, I could simply overwrite it with the correct style. The problem is I have no idea what it is that is causing it. I have tried using "inline" for example to keep the three things in one line which did not work

Comment: I was answering your question -  *assign that stylesheet to only the cover component (it has been assigning it to the entire page)*  If that's not the question then why ask it?

Comment: How do I assign a full stylesheet to one component? The line right now is this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
I tried to find syntax to assign that to an id or a class somehow but haven't been able to find anything. In other words, I get what you are saying to do, but I haven't found anything online that shows a way to assign a linked stylesheet to a single component

Comment: your meant to include your overwrite stylesheet after the bootstrap one so after that just add another link to a local stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap version 4, you can do this pretty easily with their [navbars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/). The first example can be edited to do just what you want with one change.

Their list of page links is defined like `<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">`, with the `mr-auto` keeping the content to the right. Change this to `<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">`, using `mx-auto`, which is the Bootstrap utility class for having both left and right (x-axis) margins set to auto, which will center the list.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edwardmcnealy/ju2z1mo0/3/) for a working example.

Comment: I have tried that based on other stack overflow questions and it doesn't work for my situation for some reason

Comment: Also for more information: when I copy that exact code, and remove everything from the corresponding css file, I get a very awkward navbar. The company name is in the top left, but next to that (still on the left and off-center vertically too) is home, link, dropdown, disabled, and dropdown button. In the middle and on the right there is nothing, so the menu button for example doesn't even show up anywhere. @Edward McNealy